# Unable to find JQuery code issue

Tags: jquery

I am trying to follow [this exercise](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/web-beginner-en-YFRSK/2/4#)
but I can´t follow at all. What am I doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $("div").mouseenter(function(){
            $('div').fadeTo("fast",1);
        }.mouseleave(function(){
            $('div').fadeTo("fast",0.5);
    })
);

}.mouseleave(function(){
    $('div').fadeTo("fast",0.5);    

}));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just off on the brackets / parentheses.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1);        
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Head over to jsfiddle and then hit TidyUp.  You'll notice a lot of your closures are wrong, you also defined: `.mouseleave(function(){$('div').fadeTo("fast",0.5);})` twice.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/abc123/vDbce/

HTML:

```
<div>hello world</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(
    $("div").mouseenter(function () {
        $('div').fadeTo("fast", 1);
    }).mouseleave(function () {
        $('div').fadeTo("fast", 0.5);
    })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to improve syntax format to avoid errors. Install firebug or press `shift + ctrl + j` to access error console

Answer (score 0):

Please Make Sure to Link the style-sheets & jQuery

Please try this in the HTML:

```
<head>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js" >
</head>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div").mouseenter(function(){
        your function here....
    });

    $("div").mouseleave(function(){
        Your function Here....
    });
});
```

Here is the example for your function [jQuery.mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)